# Visual Studio 2010 not showing other installed frameworks

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I transferred my project onto a different system. The project is in .NET 2.0 but this new system only had 4.0. I installed .NET 2.0 on the system, but the problem is that it is not showing Framework 2.0 in the Target Framework list.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a fresh install, Visual Studio 2010 only includes the .NET Framework 4.0 and therefore only supports targeting that version.

If you want to target earlier version of the .NET Framework, you need to install .NET 3.5 SP1, which you can download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22). Version 3.5 includes 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5.

More information here: [Targeting earlier .NET frameworks 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 using Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/12/targeting-earlier-net-frameworks-2-0-3-0-3-5-using-visual-studio-2010-beta2.aspx)